# define "the dangerous age"

Tags: meaning, idioms, slang, twentieth-century-english

How many years-old is "the dangerous age"?  Where does the term come from?  (Google doesn't seem to know.)

"I've reached **the dangerous age**, and lady, I'm going to have fun."

X Minus One - Volpa - 8/29/1957 (episode 109) - 03:28
https://archive.org/details/OTRR_X_Minus_One_Singles/XMinusOne57-08-29109Volpla.mp3

Comment: What is the context? Has the person who said it just reached a generally recognised milestone age like 18 or 21?

Comment: A science fiction show may have a different view of the dangerous age from contemporary society, and the 1950s may also differ from today. It would probably depend on the speaker (their gender, social background, nationality, occupation, etc): it's certainly not a phrase with a single, universal meaning. A dangerous age might mean one when you do stupid things, are likely to injure yourself, or are likely to harm others.

Comment: Term such as *the dangerous age* are **intended to be imprecise**. It is a misunderstanding of such a term to ask for some precise number that defines it.

Answer (score 3):

The term "a dangerous age" is used most often to refer to the susceptibility to ideas, passions, and temptations of young people as they emerge from childhood and move toward adulthood.

Patricia Meyer Spacks, in a 1978 article titled "The Dangerous Age" (*Eighteenth-Century Studies* , Summer 1978, Vol. 11, No. 4) cites two 18th century providers of advice with colorful descriptions of the concept, though neither used the term:

> I am so much aware of the Inconstancy and Unsteddiness of the  human
> Heart, the Frailty of the best Resolutions, and the most obstinate
> Virtue we can boast, the fatal Power of Temptation, the terrible
> Effects of bad Company, and the almost irresistible Force of Example,
> and withal, the Difficulty of attaining that high Pitch of Virtue
> necessary to qualify for the Enjoyment of the Christian Salvation,
> that I tremble to think what Trials you, or any Youth under my Care,
> may have to go through, and of the dreadful Hazard you run in passing
> through Life. -- James Burgh, *Youth's Friendly Monitor: Being a Set of Directions, Prudential, Moral, Religious, and Scientific* (London, 1756), pp. 58-59

and

> Alas, my brothers, in how many different directions may the
> young, the inexperienced, and the heedless, be trained on to
> destruction! In just as many as there are irregular inclinations to
> prompt, worthless companions to entice, and dangerous follies to
> ensnare them. -- James Fordyce, *Addresses to Young Men* [1777], 3rd ed., 2 vols. (London,
> 1789), I, 64

The earliest use of the term "dangerous age" in this sense that I could find in newspapers comes from earlier in the 18th century, in the Philadelphia paper *American Weekly Mercury* on  October 16, 1735. It refers to youth

> whose tender minds, like a fair Table, are capable of any Impressions,
> and are naturally disposed to receive such Doctrines as flatter their
> Passions, and open a larger Circle for the deluding Pleasures and
> Vanities to which that dangerous Age is most addicted -- *American Weekly Mercury*, October 16, 1735, p1

An even earlier example appears in a play published in 1663. In the play -- *[The Adventures of Five Hours: a Tragi-Comedy](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Adventures_of_Five_Houres_a_Tragi_Co/IGJVAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=porcia%20%22dangerous%20age%22&pg=PA3&printsec=frontcover&bsq=porcia%20%22dangerous%20age%22)* by Samuel Tuke -- a character who had been charged with the care of an orphaned young woman "Rich, Beautiful; and Young", tells the woman's brother that his sister, though she was "much more expos'd to the great World than yours"

> Yet, thanks to my Temper, cosin, as well as to her Vertue, I have seen her grow even from her Childhood, to her dangerous Age, without the least Disturbance to my rest.

Comment: ‘The dangerous age’ became a common term for the novel’s central topic: menopause

https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt1bmzngg
referring to Den farlige Alder(The Dangerous Age) (1910) by Karin Michaëlis (1872–1959)

Comment: I agree with what you wrote (great research).  And with the above comments saying this is a vague term.  I was curious if this was an expression anyone had heard of.  The menopause definition doesn't fit, because the original definition was made by a man.  The menopause definition does fit with google's ngram viewer.